# Playstore with admob flutter plugin: manifest doesn't include the AD_ID permission

Tags: flutter, admob, ads, google-play-console

I am using google_mobile_ads flutter plugin for many apps and it's working fine but one of my apps is having an issue when uploading to the Play Store

It says the androidmanifest.xml doesn't contain the "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission"

I used "Analyze APK" in the android studio then checked the merged manifest which is in "base/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml" but i found the permission already presented there!

I also used the bundletool command to verify that the manifest includes the permission ( check below )

```
$ java -jar bundletool.jar dump manifest --bundle=app-release.aab | grep AD_ID
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

Below you can find the dependencies of this app:

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
provider: ^6.0.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
transparent_image: ^2.0.0
dio: ^5.0.2
intl: ^0.18.0
timeago: ^3.4.0
share_plus: ^6.3.1
version: ^3.0.2
package_info_plus: ^3.0.3
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.2
open_store: ^0.5.0
sliding_clipped_nav_bar: ^3.1.0+4
in_app_review: ^2.0.6
google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
permission_handler: ^10.2.0
loadmore: ^2.1.0
community_charts_flutter: ^1.0.1
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3
fl_chart: ^0.62.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.1
```

[image: google_mobile_ads plugin]

Comment: I used to have this line in my manifest: `android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"`

Comment: yes i already have it in the application tag of androidmanifest `        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxx~xxxxxxx"/>
`